# Laravel Repositories inside other repositories

Tags: laravel, dependency-injection, repository-pattern

So I have recently started utilizing the Repository pattern in my work projects.  I keep running into the same question that I cannot seem to find an answer to:

**Is it OK to inject another repository into an existing repository?  What are the negative effects of doing so?**

**For instance**:

```
class CrawlsRepository implements CrawlsRepositoryInterface {

    public function __construct(ArchiveRepository $archive)
    {
        $this->archive = $archive;
    }

    ...

    ...

    public function getCrawlList()
    {
        // Do stuff with $this->crawl
        // Do stuff with $this->archive
    }
}
```

---

There are certain methods inside the `CrawlsRepository` that just *have* to use the Archive Model, meaning it needs to use the `ArchiveRepository` to maintain the pattern.

What do you guys/gals do in these situations?  I feel like I'm missing something here, I have read before, people saying that if you feel the need to pull another repository in, then evaluate weather you really need 2 separate Repositories in the first place, let me preemptively answer that, I do.

Thanks for any direction you can provide! :)

Answer (score 3):

Technically it is ok to do so. In fact it's good because you are using dependency injection, so you arn't tied to only one implementation.

Conceptually, repository represents wrappers around data source access. So I think it's okay to use another repository to abstract data retrieving further.

On the other hand when you say:
`There are certain methods inside the CrawlsRepository that just have to use the Archive Mode` then these methods have NOTHING to do inside the CrawlsRepository. They belong to the ArchiveRepository.

The use case here is when you want to return something that belongs to your CrawlRepository, but you want to return Archives that are linked in some way to your data.
In this case, the CrawlRepository HAVE TO call the ArchiveRepository to gather the needed archives before returning.

But again, if a method only need the ArchiveRepository, then it seem you are doing it wrong.

I hope my explanation is clear enough because it's quite an abstract and subjective topic.

Comment: I run into cyclic dependencies while doing constructor injection extensively. I switch to setter injection in such cases